# Why my java program is showing StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, sorting

I have written a program to sort elements of an array based on the principle of quicksort. So what the program does is that it accepts an array, assumes the first element as the pivot and then compares it with rest of the elements of the array. If the element found greater then it will store at the last of another identical array(say b) and if the element is less than the smaller than it puts that element at the beginning of the array b. in this way the pivot will find its way to the middle of the array where the elements that are on the left-hand side are smaller and at the right-hand side are greater than the pivot. Then the elements of array b are copied to the main array and this whole function is called via recursion. This is the required code.

```
package sorting;
import java.util.*;
public class AshishSort_Splitting {
    private static Scanner dogra;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        dogra=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements ");
        int n=dogra.nextInt();
        int[] a=new int[n];
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            a[i]=i;
        }
        int start=0;
        int end=n-1;
        ashishSort(a,start,end);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(+a[i]+"\n");
        }
    }
    static void ashishSort(int[]a,int start,int end)
    {
        int p;
        if(start<end)
        {
            p=ashishPartion(a,start,end);
            ashishSort(a,start,p-1);
            ashishSort(a,p+1,end);
        }
    }
    public static int ashishPartion(int[] a,int start,int end)
    {
        int n=start+end+1;
        int[] b=new int[n];
        int j=start;
        int k=end;
        int equal=a[start];
        for(int i=start+1;i<=end;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<equal)
            {
                b[j]=a[i];
                j++;
            }
            else if(a[i]>equal)
            {
                b[k]=a[i];
                k--;
            }
        }
        b[j]=equal;
        for(int l=0;l<=end;l++)
        {
            a[l]=b[l];
        }
        return j;
    }
}
```

this code works fine when I enter the value of n up to 13930, but after that, it shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sorting.AshishSort_Splitting.ashishSort(AshishSort_Splitting.java:28)
    at sorting.AshishSort_Splitting.ashishSort(AshishSort_Splitting.java:29)
```

I know the fact the error caused due to bad recursion but I tested my code multiple times and didn't find any better alternative. please help. thanks in advance.

EDIT: can someone suggest a way to overcome this.

Comment: Is your array sorted already from the start? Then plain quicksort has very bad behaviour, O(n^2), and uses O(n) stack. A common refinement is to find the median and use that as the pivot element.

Comment: @MadProgrammer ashishPartion never calls itself while ashishSort() adjusts boundaries.

Comment: @serhiyb Well, I stand correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see perfrmance issues first. I see in your partition method:

```
int n = start+end+1
```

Right there, if the method was called on an int[1000] with start=900 and end=999, you are allocating an int[1900]... Not intended, I think...!

If you are really going to trash memory instead of an in-place partitioning,
assume

```
int n = end-start+1
```

instead for a much smaller allocation, and j and k indexes b[], they would be j=0 and k=n, and return start + j.

Second, your

```
else if(a[i]<equal)
```

is not necessary and causes a bug. A simple else suffice. If you don't replace the 0's in b[j..k] you'll be in trouble when you refill a[].

Finally, your final copy is bogus, from [0 to end] is beyond the bounds of the invocation [start..end], AND most importantly, there is usually nothing of interest in b[nearby 0] with your b[] as it is. The zone of b[] (in your version) is [start..end] (in my suggested version it would be [0..n-1])

Here is my version, but it still has the O(n) stack problem that was mentioned in the comments.

```
public static int ashishPartion(int[] a, int start, int end) {
    int n = end-start + 1;
    int[] b = new int[n];
    int bj = 0;
    int bk = n-1;
    int pivot = a[start];
    for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
        if (a[i] < pivot) {
            b[bj++] = a[i];
        } else {
            b[bk--] = a[i];
        }
    }
    b[bj] = pivot;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, start, n);
    return start+bj;
}
```

If you are free to choose a sorting algo, then a mergesort would be more uniform on performance, with logN stack depth. Easy to implement.

Otherwise, you will have to de-recurse your algo, using a manual stack and that is a nice homework that I won't do for you... LOL

Comment: I changed my code to this int n = end-start+1 but still it's not working

Comment: changed my answer.